# Monotonicity in coupling of Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

> When we define a coupling of Markov chains, there is partial order on the state space but I don't understand where exactly we use monotonicity defined in the process of coupling?

For example, consider a simple random walk on a line segment $\{0,1,\cdots,n\}$. Start a chain $X_t$ from $x$ and $Y_t$ from $y$ and say $x\leq y$. Now we couple the chains $X_t$ and $Y_t$ as follows: Let $\Delta_t$ be a $\{-1,+1\}$ valued random variable and is equally likely to be $+1$ and $-1$. We use the same rule to update both $X_t,Y_t$. If $\Delta_t=+1$, move both the chains up if possible and if $\Delta_t=-1$ move both the chains down if possible. Once the two chains meet, they stay together thereafter.

> So we are able to couple two chains such that $X_t\leq Y_t$ always. But I don't understand where we use this in this upper bound proof or coupling in general?:

$$||P^t(x,.)-P^t(y,.)||_{TV}\leq \mathbf{P} _{x,y}(\tau > t)$$

where $\tau$ is the time when $X_t,Y_t$ coalesce and $||\cdot||_{TV}$ the total variation distance.

Proof: For any coupling $(X,Y)$ of two probability distributions $\mu,\nu$ and any event $A$,

\begin{align}
\mu(A)-\nu(A) &= \mathbf{P} (x\in A)-\mathbf{P} (y\in A) \\
&<=\mathbf{P} (x\in A,y\notin A) \\
&<=\mathbf{P} (X\neq Y)
\end{align}

Thus:

$$||P^t(x,.)-P^t(y,.)||_{TV}\leq \mathbf{P} _{x,y}(X_t\neq Y_t)=\mathbf{P} _{x,y}(\tau>t) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying that you don't need monotonicity to prove that coupling inequality. It refers to the coupling of two probability distributions. This is different than coupling two (or more) sample paths of a Markov chain.

Imagine running sample paths of a Markov chain starting from all points in the state space, and using the same random inputs. If all of the paths come together, they will stay together or "coupled" for all future time points by the Markov property that says "where you go just depends on where you are and some random input". If the sample paths come together, they all "are" in the same place and if you are using the same random input for all paths they will stay coupled (in this path sense).

For path coupling, you also don't need monotonicity. However, if you have it then it means that paths, run with the same random inputs, will maintain their order and never cross. So, if you are trying to check whether or not all possible sample paths have coupled (in the path sense), you could follow just two paths-- one starting from the bottom of the space and one starting from the top.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense now, thanks. So on a line segment, say a random walk is such that when it hits $0$, it jumps to $1$ with some positive probability and continues the walk. If we then look at path coupling of $X_t,Y_t$ s.t. $X_0<Y_0$, it is possible that at time $t<\tau$, where $\tau$ is coupling time, $X_t>Y_t$. Would we still analyze the same $\tau$ to get an upper bound?